# Simplify integral's to a real number

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
I=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}dx}{1+x^{6}}
$$

Simplify answer until you get an expression involving real numbers only.

I have racking my brain on this and still can't get anywhere. Firstly I'm not sure on the general solution I used which is
$$
z=e^\tfrac{(2q+1)\pi }{6}
$$
Also when it comes to using the residue theorem I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly as I can't cancel out the imaginary terms.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Try substitution $t=x^3$

Comment: ...and the answer is $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The residue theorem is kind of tedious to apply here, since the integrand resembles the derivative of the inverse tangent function, a quick substitution does the trick. Set $u=x^3$ then $du=3x^2dx$, your integral thus becomes:
$$\frac{1}{3} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+u^2}du=\frac{1}{3} [\tan^{-1}(u)]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{3} (\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property of definite integral $\color{blue}{\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\iff f(-x)=f(x)}$ Now, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 dx}{1+x^6}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 dx}{1+x^6}$$ Let, $x^3=t\implies 3x^2=dt$ 
$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{dt}{3}}{1+(t)^2}$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}[\tan^{-1}(t)]_{0}^{\infty}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}[\tan^{-1}(\infty)-\tan^{-1}(0)]$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-0\right]=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{3}}$$